# How can I use a glob with newDirectoryStream to list only files with NO extension?

Tags: java, regex, glob

This program lists contents of files with extension `.brd`, which I accomplished using "glob" `".brd"` as second argument to `Files.newDirectoryStream`. Works great and suggests that Windows file patterns are acceptable. But no.

But I have files with NO extension that I also want listed. I can't get that for any glob pattern (Windows filename pattern) I've tried.

Apparently, a glob is **not** interpreted as a Windows filename patterns, **nor** as a regex.

I have tried these various Windows patterns.

-If I use glob "*.",  I SHOULD get only files with NO extension (which is what I want), but I get NO files.

-If I use glob "* .*", I SHOULD get ALL files, but I only get files that DO have an extension. (This is just FYI.)(Please note: the glob is supposed to be "star point star" with no space; formatting issues.)

-If I use glob "*",   I get every file, which is consistent with Windows patterns. (FYI)

**What glob pattern can I get JUST files with NO extension to be processed?
Or, what regex could I use to do so?**

```
package listdirectorycontents;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListDirectoryContents {

  static DirectoryStream<Path>  directoryStream;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dov\\My Documents\\boards");

    String output, L;

    directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path, "*.brd");

      System.out.println("\n" + path + " directory contains:");
      for(Path aFile : directoryStream) {
        output = "";

        try{
          try
            (FileInputStream  inputFile = new FileInputStream(aFile.toString()); 
                      Scanner scanner   = new Scanner(inputFile)
            ) 
          {

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
              if(scanner.hasNext())
                scanner.next();

            if(scanner.hasNext()){
              L = scanner.next();

              while(L.length() == 4){
                output += L;
                L = scanner.next();
              }
              System.out.println(output);
            }
          }
       }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("\t*Not a file? " + e);}
    } 
  }
}
```

The doc for globs includes this limited help (under `getPathMatcher`):

`A FileSystem implementation supports the "glob" and "regex" syntaxes, and may support others. The value of the syntax component is compared without regard to case.
When the syntax is "glob" then the String representation of the path is matched using a limited pattern language that resembles regular expressions but with a simpler syntax. For example...`

Maybe the answer is to switch to a `FileVisitor`, but I'm hoping to rewrite as little as possible.

*** WORKAROUND ***

```
directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);  // to get all files;  no globs
...
for(Path aFile : directoryStream) 
{
  if(aFile.toString().endsWith("brd") || ! aFile.toString().contains("."))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use glob "*.", I SHOULD get only files with NO extension (which is what I want), but I get NO files. 

I'm thinking that that might be correct behavior I would expect the above to match files that look look like:
test.

Comment: I have a workaround, but I still want an answer, if any, to which glob pattern will list only files with NO extension. The workaround is to use `if(! aFile.toString().contains(".")){...}` right after the `for`.

Comment: @Travis--I agree with your expectation--that's what I want--but Java doesn't agree with us!

Comment: I think the key is from the doc: `When the syntax is "glob" then the String representation of the path is matched using a **limited** pattern language that **resembles** regular expressions but with a **simpler syntax**.`

Answer (score 2):

Java's globbing engine is consistent with POSIX globbing, which works a bit differently (and more sanely) than `cmd.exe` wildcards.  POSIX globbing is consistent with the fact that the `'.'` character is not special in POSIX filenames, contrary to Windows tradition inherited from DOS.  Thus, a `'*'` in a glob pattern can match zero or more characters, including any number of `'.'` characters, and a `'.'` appearing in a glob pattern must match a `'.'` in the filename.  This is all covered by the API docs for [FileSystem.getPathMatcher(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29), by the way, specifically:

```
*.*     Matches file names containing a dot
```

and

```
The * character matches zero or more characters of a name component without crossing directory boundaries.
```

Note no special handling documented for the `'.'` character.

Although you can match a single non-dot character with a glob pattern (i.e. `"[!.]"`), there is no subpattern repetition operator in glob syntax.

On the other hand, you can match filenames without extensions pretty easily with regex.  This pattern will do it: `"[^.]*"`, supposing that you use `Matcher.matches()` (as opposed to `Matcher.find()`, which does not require the whole string to match the pattern.)

Comment: --I'm unfamiliar with `Matcher` so I can't as yet compile successfully to test your suggestion about NO extension. I'll work on it tomorrow. Had enough today. Thanks. At present my workaround suffices, though I don't like it.

Comment: Workaround added to original question